# Combine two tables for one output with separation on different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Example of initial data:

```
 Project   | Status    |   Emp1     |   Emp2     |   Emp3     |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 Project 1 |   Active  |     10     |     10     |     20     |
 Project 2 |   Closed  |     10     |     20     |     10     |
 Project 1 |   Closed  |     20     |     10     |     20     |
 Project 1 |   Active  |     20     |     20     |     10     |
 Project 2 |   Active  |     20     |     10     |     20     |
```

Using SQL Server 2014, I have 2 queries, which I need to combine to get 1 table grouped by "Project" with new columns of "Emp" based on status.

```
 SELECT [Project],
          SUM([Emp1]) as [Emp1_Act],                    
          SUM([Emp2]) as [Emp2_Act],
          SUM([Emp2]) as [Emp3_Act],
        from t where status = 'Active' 
 SELECT [Project],
          SUM([Emp1]) as [Emp1_Clo],                    
          SUM([Emp2]) as [Emp2_Clo],
          SUM([Emp2]) as [Emp3_Clo],
        from t where status = 'Closed'
```

Requested data:

```
   Project   | Emp1_Act | Emp2_Act | Emp3_Act | Emp1_Clo | Emp2_Clo | Emp3_Clo |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Project 1 |    30    |    30    |    30    |    10    |    20    |    10    |
   Project 2 |    20    |    10    |    20    |    20    |    10    |    20    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a fixed number of columns, you should be able to get away with a standard pivot query:

```
SELECT Project,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN Emp1 ELSE 0 END) AS Emp1_Act,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN Emp2 ELSE 0 END) AS Emp2_Act,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN Emp3 ELSE 0 END) AS Emp3_Act,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN Emp1 ELSE 0 END) AS Emp1_Clo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN Emp2 ELSE 0 END) AS Emp2_Clo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN Emp3 ELSE 0 END) AS Emp3_Clo
FROM t
GROUP BY Project
```